# Can a liquid shrink as something is dissolved into it?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry

Not much more to add.   By shrink, I mean become more dense at the same pressure and temperature.

And I don't mean vol(A+B) < vol(A) + vol(B).   I'm sure this is possible.

Is it possible to get vol(A+B) < vol(A)?

Comment: I deleted an inappropriate comment and the following discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes

http://www.nuffieldfoundation.org/practical-physics/volume-change-dissolving-salt-water

This definitely is not material science but chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  Adding a salt to water in reasonably small amounts often results in a volume shrinkage such that vol(water+salt) < vol(water).  A typical example is sodium chloride.

This works because in the liquid state water has an open structure.  The presence of a solute can cause this open structure to break down and the solution to become more dense.